# I pass the test case, but fail to verify, why?

Tags: python

I am having similar issues as Will Njundong's post [Why could this code possibly be failing a test case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41933895/why-could-this-code-possibly-be-failing-a-test-case#), where I fail two of the 5 cases

```
foobar:~/power_hungry user$ verify solution.py 
Verifying solution...

Test 1 passed!
Test 2 passed!
Test 3 failed.
Test 4 failed.
Test 5 passed!
```

Can't figure out why my code is failing, see below:

```
def answer(xs):
    negArr = 0
    product = 1
    for number in xs:
        if number < 0:
            negArr += 1
    xs.sort()
    while 0 in xs: xs.remove(0)
    if negArr % 2 != 0:
        xs.pop(negArr-1)
    for x in xs:
        product *= x
    return product
```

My code passes the two test cases given (see below) what am I missing? Please advise

## Test cases

Inputs:
    (int list) xs = [2, 0, 2, 2, 0]
Output:
    (string) "8"

Inputs:
    (int list) xs = [-2, -3, 4, -5]
Output:
    (string) "60"

## Power Hungry

Commander Lambda's space station is HUGE. And huge space stations take a LOT of power. Huge space stations with doomsday devices take even more power. To help meet the station's power needs, Commander Lambda has installed solar panels on the station's outer surface. But the station sits in the middle of a quasar quantum flux field, which wreaks havoc on the solar panels. You and your team of henchmen has been assigned to repair the solar panels, but you can't take them all down at once without shutting down the space station (and all those pesky life support systems!).

You need to figure out which sets of panels in any given array you can take offline to repair while still maintaining the maximum amount of power output per array, and to do THAT, you'll first need to figure out what the maximum output of each array actually is. Write a function answer(xs) that takes a list of integers representing the power output levels of each panel in an array, and returns the maximum product of some non-empty subset of those numbers. So for example, if an array contained panels with power output levels of [2, -3, 1, 0, -5], then the maximum product would be found by taking the subset: xs[0] = 2, xs[1] = -3, xs[4] = -5, giving the product 2*(-3)*(-5) = 30.  So answer([2,-3,1,0,-5]) will be "30".

Each array of solar panels contains at least 1 and no more than 50 panels, and each panel will have a power output level whose absolute value is no greater than 1000 (some panels are malfunctioning so badly that they're draining energy, but you know a trick with the panels' wave stabilizer that lets you combine two negative-output panels to produce the positive output of the multiple of their power values). The final products may be very large, so give the answer as a string representation of the number.

## Test cases

Inputs:
    (int list) xs = [2, 0, 2, 2, 0]
Output:
    (string) "8"

Inputs:
    (int list) xs = [-2, -3, 4, -5]
Output:
    (string) "60"

## Revised code 2

Accounting for single negative number & returning string

```
def answer(xs):
    negArr = 0
    product = 1
    for number in xs:
        if number < 0:
            negArr += 1
    xs.sort()
    while 0 in xs: xs.remove(0)
    print(xs)
    if not xs:
        return 0
    if len(xs) == 1:
        if xs[0] < 0:
            return 0
    elif negArr % 2 != 0:
        xs.pop(negArr-1)
    for x in xs:
        product *= x
    return str(product)
```

Comment: Are you sure you correctly understand the problem you're supposed to solve? (Which you haven't told us, by the way. No, the link doesn't count.)

Comment: Are you sure those are really the test cases you're failing? Have you read the answer to the question you linked? If you're solving the same problem, you have a very similar bug.

Comment: added the problem. will investigate further on my side.

Comment: not sure I face the same issue. If the array contains a single negative number, that number gets excluded. Any other thoughts?

Comment: it's not clear to me what you're supposed to return if xs is a single negative number ex. `xs = [-8]` but currently you're returning 1, which seems wrong? I would try making it so that it either returns 0 or that negative number in that case and see if that solves one of the test cases and then we can go from there. the other answer suggests you should be returning the negative number. on top add `if len(xs) == 1: return xs[0]` and see what that does. next try `if len(xs) == 1: if xs[0] < 0: return 0 else: return xs[0]`

Comment: also didn't they ask you to return a string? change last line to `return str(product)`. and fix any other returns as well. please report back as I'm curious!

Comment: good catch on the single negative digit scenario. I see how I face similar issues. If a single negative number, solution, return zero. 1 test down, 1 to go

Comment: forgot str on `return '0'`

Comment: figured it out. you are returning 1 for [0] or [0,0,0,0] instead of 0. did that solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't accounting for some edge cases:

1. Single negative number `[-8]`
2. 0's and 1 negative number `[0,0,-8,0]`
3. 0's `[0,0,0]`

Comment: at this point, I am accounting for Single negative number (i.e. [-8])
Any number of 0's (i.e. [0] or [0,0,0]).

Comment: Did you try returning xs[0] if negative and len(xs) == 1 instead of 0?

Comment: Np! Can you accept my answer? When answering homework type questions we're supposed to steer you in the right direction, that's why I didn't provide code.

Answer (score 0):

This was the winning ticket:

```
def answer(xs):
    negArr = 0
    product = 1
    for number in xs:
        if number < 0:
            negArr += 1
    xs.sort()
    if not xs:
        return 0
    if len(xs) == 1:
        return xs[0]
    while 0 in xs: xs.remove(0)
    if negArr % 2 != 0:
        xs.pop(negArr-1)
    for x in xs:
        product *= x
    print(xs)
    if len(xs) == 0:
        return str(0)
    else:
        return str(product)
```